# Fatal error on omitted fields in SOAP-request

Tags: soap, soap-client, php

I'm building a SOAP client for sending information to a SOAP service defined with a WSDL. When posting data to the service in SoapUI, I'm able to omit the fields I don't have values for, but in PHP I'm getting a fatal error.

Is there a way to have SOAPClient in PHP omit fields? The object I'm passing to SOAPClient looks like this:

```
Kunde Object
(
    [kundenr] => 1008911
    [contact_id] => 10941
    [kundenavn] => 
    [organisasjonsnr] => 
    [addresse] => Addresse Object
        (
            [postadresse1] => 
            [postadresse2] => 
            [postadresse3] => 
            [postadresse] => 
            [gateadresse1] => 
            [gateadresse2] => 
            [gateadresse3] => 
            [gateadresse] => 
            [county] => 
            [kommunenr] => 
            [stat] => 
            [postnr] => 
            [poststed] => 
            [landkode] => 
            [land] => 
            [adresslayout] => 
        )

    [kontakt] => Kontakt Object
        (
            [tlfnr] => 
            [tlfbeskrivelse] => 
            [faxnr] => 
            [faxbeskrivelse] => 
            [mailadresse] => 
            [webadresse] => 
        )

    [person] => Person Object
        (
            [customerId] => 
            [personId] => 
            [contact_id] => 
            [fornavn] => 
            [etternavn] => 
            [brukernavn] => 
            [epost] => 
            [tlf] => 
            [kundetype] => 40
            [addresse] => Addresse Object
                (
                    [postadresse1] => 
                    [postadresse2] => 
                    [postadresse3] => 
                    [postadresse] => 
                    [gateadresse1] => 
                    [gateadresse2] => 
                    [gateadresse3] => 
                    [gateadresse] => 
                    [county] => 
                    [kommunenr] => 
                    [stat] => 
                    [postnr] => 
                    [poststed] => 
                    [landkode] => 
                    [land] => 
                    [adresslayout] => 
                )

        )

    [faultmsg] => Faultmsg Object
        (
            [Type] => 
            [Melding] => 
            [Detalj] => 
        )

    [avdeling] => 
    [kundetype] => 40
    [informasjon] => 
    [aktiv] => 
    [stopputsendelse] => 
    [aco_kunde] => 
    [uf_kunde] => 
    [gan_kunde] => 
    [kunde] => 10941
)
```

I would like to for instance omit the Kunde->kundenavn property from the object, but that gives me this fatal error:

> [13-Aug-2012 07:01:50] PHP Fatal error:  SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object
>   has no 'kundenavn' property in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be suffering from [PHP Bug #50997: SOAP Error when trying to submit 2nd Element of a choice](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50997)

Or it may be required field in the WSDL so you're stuck with it either way most likely. Sorry!

Comment: I guess so... I've sort of worked around it for now, but it would be best not having to do that. The fields aren't required, so i think it's the former problem...